# Kubuntu 16.04 brightness not working HP Pavillion DV 6

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, brightness

I would like to get a current solution to the brightness settings as I have seen other other solutions to the problem for the brightness not working.

1. Can someone please explain why the brightness isn't working in the buntus?
2. How to fix my brightness, so that I can set it from my  F2 and F3 keys.

I have a HP Pavillion DV 6

Running the `cat /lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service` command I get the following:

> [Unit]
>   Description=Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of %i
>   Documentation=man:systemd-backlight@.service(8)
>   DefaultDependencies=no
>   RequiresMountsFor=/var/lib/systemd/backlight
>   Conflicts=shutdown.target
>   After=systemd-remount-fs.service
>   Before=sysinit.target shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight load %i
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-backlight save %i
TimeoutSec=90s

And running the `lspci | grep VGA` I get the following output:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (rev ff)

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/812373/edit) your question with the output of `cat /lib/systemd/system/systemd-backlight@.service`.

Comment: Also, do you have a graphics card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution on this page..

[From: It's FOSS website](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)